Android app to move files automatically to SD card without manually creating folder pairs?
I know that there are already a few threads out there, where people are promoting different applications for Android file transfer. Some even call these «automated», even though you have to define each source folder and each destination folder separately, as well as create the folder pairs manually. I don't really understand what would make this automatic, though.
What I am looking for is similar to something I had in-built in my old Nokia Android a few years back: just push a button in the storage manager, and the system will transfer all images, videos, PDFs etc. to SD card automatically. What makes the situation rather troublesome at the moment, is the outright diaspora of files in my Android system. For example, you can find images from Downloads (general folder), Downloads (browser's folder), Downloads (WhatsApp / Telegram / Signal ... each one with a separate folder), Screenshots folder, Camera folder, different image editor applications' folders ... I think you get the point.
Now, repeat the excercise with audio files and video files. Even my FoxIt PDF-reader has a stash of its own!
Therefore, I am looking for something that could do the trick by a single click (no pun intended). Any suggestions would be welcome!
Over and out.

I'm not sure about your automation confusion - the moving part is automated ofc. The reason not everything is moved is because you can't just assume all the images should be on SD. They could be part of some app that doesn't want them moved. And in-build Android storage choice usually revolved around just moving specific files as well - camera, whole app data, etc.

@Destroy666 dunno either how Nokia had resolved this, but surely some standard download folders, camera etc. If I have to pair up and define every single folder, I don't really understand what's automatic there anymore.

These can be in various directories on various OSes like MIUI etc. If OS itself doesn't provide such method, it's doubtful that an application will cover all of them on all Android versions
